# What type of adhesive should I use to reattach cap stones on a sea wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, adhesive, masonry, stone

I need to re-affix the stones. The flat-topped concrete flat-stone-capped seawall is in the atmospheric zone, but it takes a beating from waves during storms. It has no rebars protruding. I'm considering to re-affix the stones with PPC (Portland Pozzolana Cement) (if best, please suggest grade) vs. epoxy vs. polymer-reinforced PPC. I'm open to all suggestions.

What adhesive would have the greatest shear strength and would endure for the longest time against salt water and against freezes/thaws?

Comment: What is PPC? Please use unabbreviated generic industry terms as many of us are unfamiliar and product (brand) recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Are there any sort of mechanical fasteners, like re-bar in holes, or is it just smooth, flat stone surface to smooth, flat stone surface?

Comment: The sea water and waves will win, eventually.

Comment: Requested details have been added to the Q..

Comment: The old roman's made concrete that lasted, but unknown if the recipe has been found yet, but they think sea water was part of it.

Comment: "Marine" marketed stuff tends to be for boats, where calling up 3M might encourage you for one of their products (they don't mention stone as a substrate, but that may be a marketing choice instead of a technical spec). I would look at swimming pool stone tile products. A pool's chlorine content is something like 10% of seawater, so it's not a perfect fit, but it's close. Sika's hardscaping glue says no on chlorine, so I would worry about any hardscaping product that doesn't mention saltwater in its technical data.

Comment: Crip659: "Veni, vidi, coniuncta lapides"